# Equalizing the elements in a list

Tags: python

I'm attempting to equalize a list of elements. In short, I have an array of x length with each element y being in range from 0 - 100000. To accomplish what I'm trying to do, all elements in the list must be relatively equal to each other (as far as is possible).

Here's some sample output of my current function:

```
>>> equal([1, 4, 1])
[2, 2, 2]
>>> equal([2, 4, 5, 9])
[5, 5, 5, 5]
>>> equal([2, 2])
[2, 2]
>>> equal([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
>>> equal([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 20, 30, 40])
[15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15]
>>> equal([343, 452, 948, 283, 394, 238, 283, 984, 236, 847, 203])
[474, 474, 474, 474, 474, 474, 474, 474, 473, 473, 473]
```

And the associated code:

```
def equal(l):
    # The number of times we distribute to the new loop
    loops = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l)

    # Initializes a new list as such: [0, 0, 0 .. len(l)]
    nl = [0 for x in range(len(l))]

    # Counts how far we've iterated into our new list
    x = 0
    for i in range(loops):
        # Add 1 to this element and move on to the next element in the list
        nl[x] += 1
        x += 1

        # Ensure we don't traverse past the end of the list
        if x > len(nl) - 1:
            x = 0

    return nl
```

The problem right now is that once you get to extremely large lists (100+ elements with large values) it gets really slow. Is there some idiom I'm missing here that would make this more efficient?

Comment: What if you cannot make all of them equal?

Comment: All you want is the mean of the list items, so `sum(my_list)/float(len(my_ist))`  should do it for you.

Comment: The that's why I put 'as far as possible' in parenthesis. So [2,1] would return [2,1] because it can't be equalized any further past that point.

Comment: Ashwini: No, I need an equalized list. If you could post an answer that shows how you can extrapolate your equation into an equalized list (like I have shown in my examples above), that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

All of your examples have output lists with all equal integers [*], which of course is not possible in the general case.

[*] except one, where it seems you want earlier items to be bigger, later ones smaller, independently of what original items where big or small; see later if **that** is in fact your spec.

Assuming (you never actually bother to **say** that, you know!-) that "all items integers" is a constraint, I'd start with

```
minel = sum(l) // len(l)
```

which is the minimum value to assign to each output element.  This leaves a "shortage" of

```
numex = sum(l) - minel * len(l)
```

items that must be set to `minel + 1` to keep the `sum` equal (another constraint you never clearly express...:-).

Which ones?  Presumably those that were largest in the first place.

(Added: or maybe not, according to your last example, where it seems the items that need to be made larger are just the earliest ones.  If that's the case, then obviously:

```
[minel+1] * numex + [minel] * (len(l) - numex)
```

will be fine.  The rest of the answer assumes you may want **some** connection of input items to corresponding output ones, a harder problem).

So pick those, e.g as `bigs = set(heapq.nlargest(l, numex))`, and

```
[minel + (x in bigs) for x in l]
```

is going to be a pretty close approximation to the "equalized" list you seek (exploiting the fact that a bool is worth 0 or 1 in arithmetic:-).

The one little glitch is for a list with duplicates -- more than `numex` items might satisfy the `x in bigs` test!

In this case you presumably want to randomly pick **which** `numex` items get to be incremented by 1 (the others staying at `minel`).  But guessing exactly what you want for such a case in your totally under-specified desires is stretching guesses a point too much, so I'll let it rest here for now -- you can clarify your specs, ideally with examples where this formula doesn't do what you exactly want and what you would want instead, by editing your question appropriately.

Comment: _"All of your examples have output lists with all equal integers"_ That's not true; just look at his last example ;)

Comment: @Eithos, you're right -- let me edit the A accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I added that in at the last minute because I realized the examples were all equal at first.

Comment: @JoshuaGilman, edited my A to show how to trivially get "the first X items larger, the rest smaller" if **that** is your spec.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.  Simply find the whole number average and remainder and return the appropriate number of `average+1` and `average` elements to give the same sum.  The code below leverages the builtin `divmod` to give the whole quotient and remainder, and the fact that multiplying a list such as `[x]*5` returns `[x,x,x,x,x]`:

```
def equal(l):
    q,r = divmod(sum(l),len(l))
    return [q+1]*r + [q]*(len(l)-r)

print(equal([2,1]))
print(equal([1, 4, 1]))
print(equal([2, 4, 5, 9]))
print(equal([2, 2]))
print(equal([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
print(equal([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 20, 30, 40]))
print(equal([343, 452, 948, 283, 394, 238, 283, 984, 236, 847, 203]))
```

Output:

```
[2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[5, 5, 5, 5]
[2, 2]
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
[15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15]
[474, 474, 474, 474, 474, 474, 474, 474, 473, 473, 473]
```